# Qt - Create WriteOnly and ReadOnly socket

Tags: qt, sockets, readonly, writeonly

I have a socketDescriptor.

I need to two sockets. One of them just for ReadOnly and another one for WriteOnly.

Is it impossible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Qt's sockets don't support having more than one socket object per native socket, but you can approximate this by creating appropriate unidirectional interfaces.

In the example below, the interfaces don't perform any buffering, thus they enforce that there is only once of each kind of interface per socket. Once you use the interface, you shouldn't be using the socket directly.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/socket-split-43409221
#include <QtNetwork>

class SocketBase : public QIODevice {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit SocketBase(QAbstractSocket * parent) : QIODevice{parent} {
      connect(parent, &QAbstractSocket::connected, this, &SocketBase::connected);
      connect(parent, &QAbstractSocket::disconnected, this, &SocketBase::disconnected);
      connect(parent, &QAbstractSocket::stateChanged, this, [this](QAbstractSocket::SocketState state){
         emit stateChanged(state);
         setOpenMode(m_dev->openMode());
      });
      connect(parent,
              static_cast<void(QAbstractSocket::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)>(&QAbstractSocket::error),
              this, [this](QAbstractSocket::SocketError error){
         setErrorString(m_dev->errorString());
         emit this->error(error);
      });
      setOpenMode(m_dev->openMode());
   }
   QAbstractSocket::SocketError error() const {
      return m_dev->error();
   }
   QAbstractSocket::SocketState state() const {
      return m_dev->state();
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void connected();
   Q_SIGNAL void disconnected();
   Q_SIGNAL void error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError);
   Q_SIGNAL void stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState);
   bool isSequential() const override { return true; }
protected:
   QAbstractSocket * const m_dev = static_cast<QAbstractSocket*>(parent());
};

class ReadSocket : public SocketBase {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit ReadSocket(QAbstractSocket * parent) : SocketBase(parent) {
      for (auto proxy : parent->findChildren<ReadSocket*>())
         Q_ASSERT(proxy == this);
      connect(m_dev, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, &QIODevice::readyRead);
   }
   bool atEnd() const override {
      return QIODevice::atEnd() && m_dev->atEnd();
   }
   qint64 bytesAvailable() const override {
      return m_dev->bytesAvailable();
   }
   bool canReadLine() const override {
      return m_dev->canReadLine();
   }
protected:
   qint64 readData(char * data, qint64 maxLength) override {
      return m_dev->read(data, maxLength);
   }
   qint64 readLineData(char *data, qint64 maxLength) override {
      return m_dev->readLine(data, maxLength);
   }
   qint64 writeData(const char *, qint64) override {
      return -1;
   }
};

class WriteSocket : public SocketBase {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit WriteSocket(QAbstractSocket * parent) : SocketBase(parent) {
      for (auto proxy : parent->findChildren<WriteSocket*>())
         Q_ASSERT(proxy == this);
      connect(m_dev, &QIODevice::bytesWritten, this, &QIODevice::bytesWritten);
   }
   qint64 bytesToWrite() const override {
      return m_dev->bytesToWrite();
   }
   bool flush() {
      return m_dev->flush();
   }
protected:
   qint64 readData(char *, qint64) override {
      return -1;
   }
   qint64 writeData(const char * data, qint64 length) override {
      return m_dev->write(data, length);
   }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
   QHostAddress addr{"127.0.0.1"};
   quint16 port{9341};

   QTcpServer server;
   if (! server.listen(addr, port)) qFatal("can't listen");
   QObject::connect(&server, &QTcpServer::newConnection, &server, [&]{
      auto s = server.nextPendingConnection();
      QObject::connect(s, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, s, [s]{
         s->write(s->readAll());
      });
      QObject::connect(s, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, s, &QObject::deleteLater);
   });

   const char data_[] = "dhfalksjdfhaklsdhfklasdfs";
   auto const data = QByteArray::fromRawData(data_, sizeof(data_));
   QTcpSocket client;
   WriteSocket writer(&client);
   ReadSocket reader(&client);
   QObject::connect(&writer, &WriteSocket::connected, [&]{
      writer.write(data);
   });
   QObject::connect(&reader, &ReadSocket::readyRead, [&]{
      if (reader.bytesAvailable() >= data.size()) {
         auto const read = reader.read(data.size());
         Q_ASSERT(read == data);
         qApp->quit();
      }
   });
   client.connectToHost(addr, port);
   return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```